# Bootstrap 3 grid row span

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I'm trying to make a grid based on bootstrap only I need 1 div to span 3 rows.
I've added a picture below inclusive the code I used. For the main grid I used a generator but now I get stuck.

The div which says REMOVE I added as a dummy and need to be removed. only when I do that the div with MOST READ will move to the right and closes the gap.
What I'm trying to achieve is that COMMENTS - SITE FEED will span 3 rows (vertically downwards) next to, in the spot light, quiz/poll and most read.

How can I do this with wrapping some stuff so it not move and shift anymore :-)

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">col-md-12 - MARQUE</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">col-md-8 - CAROUSEL</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">col-md-4 - MY STUFF</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">col-md-12 - 5 ARTICLES</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - LOCAL NEWS</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - SEGMENTS NEWS</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - COUNTRY NEWS</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - TWITTER</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - BLOG</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - IN SPOT LIGHT</div>   
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - - COMMENTS - SITE FEED</div>  
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - STEEL FABRIC</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - QUIZ/POLL</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - remove !!!!</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - MOST READ</div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - UNDETER 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - UNDETER 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - UNDETER 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3 - SHAREHOLDER</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">col-md-12 - QUICK ACCESS</div>
</div>
```

I have not tried the suggested code but I will soon. I've noticed I was not so clear after all so I made a second picture. The Red block represent the COMMENTS SITE FEED div how i need it in the end result. Hopefully it helps a bit thanks so far guys. it#s really appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJiIw.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have to nest row in another row to achieve your goal.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 red col">col-md-12 - MARQUE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 blue col">col-md-8 - CAROUSEL</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 green col">col-md-4 - MY STUFF</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 orange col">col-md-12 - 5 ARTICLES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 blue col">col-md-6 - LOCAL NEWS</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 green col">col-md-6 - SEGMENTS NEWS</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 green col">col-md-6 - COUNTRY NEWS</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 blue col">col-md-6 - TWITTER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 orange col">col-md-3 - BLOG</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 blue col">col-md-3 - IN SPOT LIGHT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 green col">col-md-3 - STEEL FABRIC</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 orange col">col-md-3 - QUIZ/POLL</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 red col">col-md-6 - MOST READ</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 green comments-site-feed">
          col-md-6 - - COMMENTS - SITE FEED
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 green col">col-md-3 - UNDETER 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blue col">col-md-3 - UNDETER 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 orange col">col-md-3 - UNDETER 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 green col">col-md-3 - SHAREHOLDER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 red col">c`ol-md-12 - QUICK ACCESS</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 125px;
}
.row > .red {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
.row .blue {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.row .green {
  background: green;
}
.row .orange {
  background: orange;
}
.row > .comments-site-feed {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  height: 375px;
}
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/oLBByW)**

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what exactly you are going for but I think you may have to nest some elements in order to get the rowspan effect you are looking for.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">COMMENTS - SITE FEED</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">STEEL FABRIC</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">QUIZ/POLL</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">MOST READ</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group these divs as two columns.

The following should achieve the desired grid layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - BLOG</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - IN SPOT LIGHT</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - STEEL FABRIC</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 - QUIZ/POLL</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">col-md-12 - MOST READ</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        col-md-6 - - COMMENTS - SITE FEED
    </div>
</div>
```